# Plugin Wordpress para restringir acesso a arquivos somente após cadastro

Tags: wordpress

Estou com um cliente que tem um site em Wordpress e quer limitar o acesso a certos arquivos PDF somente para quem fizer o cadastro no site. O problema é que são vários PDFs e o registro feito pelo usuário deve valer apenas para aquele PDF em específico, não podendo ver assim os demais, a menos que ele solicite aos administradores do site e eles façam a liberação do novo PDF.

Tenho instalado neste site o plugin "Ultimate Membership Pro", porém não encontrei nele uma forma de limitar os acessos em cada registro um PDF.

Gostaria de saber se é possível isto no Wordpress, via código ou plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Tente esse [CopySafe PDF Protection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-copysafe-pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Cria um custom post type.

2 - Instala o plugin ACF.

3 - Cria um grupo de campo, chamado: PDF

4 - Cria a regra para ser mostrado somente para o seu custom post type

5 - Cria os campos para por o pdf, do tipo arquivo e um select ou checkbox ou radio com os valores referentes aos tipos de usuários do wordpress...administrator, editor, author, subscriber...

6 - Vai no menu do seu cistom post type, cria um novo, sobe o arquivo e seta a role, no select. Então aquele PDF, registro criado, estará referenciado a uma role, específica.

7 - Na hora de listar no site, esses arquivos, faça a chamada normal(loop) e faça uma verificação do usuário que está lgoado, naquele momento e mostre somente os arquivos referentes a sua role, com um IF.